# make project run on start up after using installshield light

Tags: installation, installshield, startup

I want my solution run on startup after installing it using installshield light on VS 2012. is there an easy way to do so? also, is there a main difference between doing it with registry key or doing it with shortcut in the startup folder?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: what you have tried please show here..for better answers..

Comment: I haven't tried anythings, just looked around for "start project on startup", like there is a "add desktop shortcut" and haven't found anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an article that describes the behavior of the different options:

[INFO: Run, RunOnce, RunServices, RunServicesOnce and Startup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365)

The main thing to realize is that your program should not require UAC elevation.  It goes against Windows Logo guidelines to put an elevated application in the automatic startup.